# Issue With __block And CLGecoder in ios?

Tags: objective-c, ios, objective-c-blocks, clgeocoder

i write code of CLGecoder and the code are

```
-(NSString *)GetCurrentAddress:(CLLocation *)Location
{
  __block NSString  *locatedaddress;
    CLGeocoder *Gecoder=[[CLGeocoder alloc]init];
    [Gecoder reverseGeocodeLocation: Location completionHandler: 
     ^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

         //Get address
         CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

         NSLog(@"Placemark array: %@",placemark.addressDictionary );

         //String to address
       locatedaddress = [[placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"] componentsJoinedByString:@", "];

         //Print the location in the console
         NSLog(@"Currently address is: %@",locatedaddress);


     }];
    return locatedaddress;
}
```

Problem is locatedaddress inside The completionHandler Has Value But Outside Is Not ?
Any One Can Help Me ?
Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 3):

The geocoder is asynchronous -- which by definition means you cannot get the result immediately. You must use the completion handler to do whatever you want to do with the result.